# Dell U2515H 1440p on Asus N56VZ?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, external-display, asus-laptop

I have decided to buy an external monitor. I'm going to get the Dell U2515H (1440p).

I'm using an Asus N56VZ laptop at the moment, which has a GT 650M graphics card, as well as an integrated Intel HD 4000 card. The computer only has an HDMI and a VGA output. I have not been able to find out what HDMI version it is. (I have heard that you need 1.3 or newer to output 1440p).

I have a couple questions:

1. Would my Asus N56VZ be able to output 1440p to an external monitor over HDMI (preferably at 60hz)?
2. Does the Dell U2515H accept 1440p resolutions over HDMI, or is it capped at 1080p over HDMI as some other Dell monitors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The HDMI revision isn't important, HDMI is HDMI for the purposes your using, it only matters, if you want to display at higher resolutions (4k or 3d) and some other reasons, but 1440P is not one of those resolutions that are nto supported by all HDMI revisions.  [GTX 650M Specifications](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-650m/specifications)

Comment: Its safe to assume if the monitor has HDMI, then its using a revision of the HDMI specifications, that can support 1440P.  MHL fits that bill: https://www.bing.com/search?q=MHL&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN

Comment: According to Wikipedia, HDMI v1.2 and earlier support a maximum resolution of 1080p at 60hz. And I've heard about Dell monitors that only can display 1440p over DisplayPort, even though they have an HDMI input as well.

Comment: I provided you the specifications for your GPU it supports 1440p which means it's not using hdmi 1.2 but 1.4 (verified based on documented features of Kepler  core )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_(microarchitecture) Anyways I feel I did all the research....

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1: yes, no problem

Answer to question 2: yes it does*

*It can support 1440p, but it might not work immediately at the right resolution. If it doesn't, you might have to create a custom resolution (source:[1]). It seems that this model of monitor sometimes requests the wrong resolution. You can set a custom resolution using for instance the nircmd tool [2], but there are many other options as well.

[1] http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19626476 
[2] http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdisplay.html